# Laravel Blade engine caches @extend

Tags: php, laravel

I'm stuck:

I'm building a dynamic form builder:

I have input types like this ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJfeH.png)):

- List item
- master_pages

  - fields

    - date.blade.php
    - datetime.blade.php
    - email.blade.php
    - field.blade.php
    - image.blade.php
    - input.blade.php
    - number.blade.php
    - textarea.blade.php
    - wysiwyg.blade.php

All field blade templates extends to field.blade.php

When I'm including them dynamically like this ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikxeg.png)):

```
<div class="bg-light p-3 fields">
    @if(isset($section->fields))
        @foreach($section->fields as $id => $field)
            @include('admin.master_pages.fields.' . $field['type'], ['id' => $id, 'type' => $field['type'], 'field' => $field])
        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

Laravel blade engine includes same file for every input type. Like caching include.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure al templates are in in `$section->fields`? What happens if you dump out `$field['type']`?

Comment: It's ok. There is no problem when i dump it, prints right file name(input name)

Comment: so if in the loop you print `@include('admin.master_pages.fields.' . $field['type'])` this gives something like `admin.master_pages.fields.email`? Can I also assume that there is another top level folder of admin that your screenshot does not show?

Comment: Yes, it prints **admin.master_pages.fields.email** like these kind of strings. Yes, there is a root folder of views. I seperated cms and admin views.